# barchart in pgfplots looks really bad

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, pgfplots

[image]

Problems:

- The bar value "90" is written over a black line, almost impossible to read
- The value "58" is written over an x tick, hard to ready
- Bar spacing is bad. There is too much space between the bars, and there is no space above/below the top and the bottom bar.

Some of this might be my fault, but I would expect that this kind of mess should be automatically avoided by pgfplots. What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        xbar,
            xmin=0.0,
            xmax=91.6666666667,
            width=12cm,
            height={ 1cm + ( 3.0 * 1cm ) },
    symbolic y coords={{Térritmus},{Mozgásritmus},{Formaritmus}},
    xlabel={Pontérték \%},
    ytick=data,
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords align = {horizontal}
]
\addplot [draw=black, fill=cyan!40!black] coordinates {
    (58.3333333333,{Térritmus})
    (91.6666666667,{Mozgásritmus})
    (90.0,{Formaritmus})

};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\caption{Ritmus}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first problem is caused by `xmax=91.6666666667`. Since you have set it, `pgfplots` does not try to calculate the upper x axis limit. Moreover, nodes near every coordinate are not taken into account while calculating the limits.

To solve the first problem, remove `xmax=91.6666666667` and add `enlarge x limits={rel=0.13,upper}` (the value 0.13 have to be selected arbitrarily).
To solve the second and third problem, add `enlarge y limits=0.4` (again, 0.4 is arbitrary).

The another issue is that my LaTeX with `pgfplots` 1.8 does not want to compile the code with diacritics in `symbolic y coords`. You can use `ytick` and `yticklabels` to be 100% reproducible.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xbar,
    xmin=0.0,
    width=12cm,
    height=4cm,
    enlarge x limits={rel=0.13,upper},
    ytick={1,2,3},
    yticklabels={{Térritmus},{Mozgásritmus},{Formaritmus}},
    enlarge y limits=0.4,
    xlabel={Pontérték \%},
    ytick=data,
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords align=horizontal
]
\addplot [draw=black, fill=cyan!40!black] coordinates {
    (58.3333333333,1)
    (91.6666666667,2)
    (90.0,3)

};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: compiled code]

To solve the first problem you can also move the nodes inside the bars. But you should increase the bar width (e.g., to `\baselineskip`):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xbar,
    bar width=\baselineskip,
    xmin=0.0,
    width=12cm,
    height=4cm,
    ytick={1,2,3},
    yticklabels={{Térritmus},{Mozgásritmus},{Formaritmus}},
    enlarge y limits=0.4,
    xlabel={Pontérték \%},
    ytick=data,
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords align=left,
    every node near coord/.style={color=white}
]
\addplot [draw=black, fill=cyan!40!black] coordinates {
    (58.3333333333,1)
    (91.6666666667,2)
    (90.0,3)

};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: compiled code]

Comment: Although I noticed that below 10% percent value, moving nodes into bars doesn't look good either. Goes out of the bar on the left side. So in some cases, `enlarge x limits` is better.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things you can try here: perhaps

```
every node near coord/.append style={anchor=east},
```

which gives

[image: screenshot]

or else changing `xmax` to something else, which gives (for example)

[image]

Furthermore, you can change the `height` and `bar width` to get round the overlapping with the `xtick`

```
  height={ .5\textwidth},
  bar width= .8cm,
```

[image: screenshot]

In either case, I would remove `resizebox` and use `width=\textwidth`; using `resizebox` may lead to inconsistent font sizes in your diagram, which would negate part of the point of using `pgfplots` in the first place.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: on, trace: yes}
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            xbar,
            xmin=0.0,
            xmax=110,
            height={ .5\textwidth},
            bar width= .8cm,
            symbolic y coords={{Térritmus},{Mozgásritmus},{Formaritmus}},
            xlabel={Pontérték \%},
            ytick=data,
            nodes near coords,
            nodes near coords align = {horizontal},
            %every node near coord/.append style={anchor=east},
            width=\textwidth,
        ]
        \addplot [draw=black, fill=cyan!40!black] coordinates {
            (58.3333333333,{Térritmus})
            (91.6666666667,{Mozgásritmus})
            (90.0,{Formaritmus})

        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: For some reason, using `width=\textwidth` is wrong. The whole figure goes out of margins. [Example](http://i.imgur.com/JzZUJRi.png) This is why I started to use a fixed size. I'm not sure how to overcome that problem.